Let's get critical: Apr 2015 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Chinese Language Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Difference between 别人 and 人家

Net Score: 9 (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)


How to translate 掩耳盗铃 into English?

Net Score: 7 (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)


Can I use 的 between the name and 他们

Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)


what is the difference between 现场 and 地点?

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)


How do you learn and remember 左 and 右?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)


Why 干菜类 was mistakenly translated to Fuck Vegetables?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)


Did some people only have names like 张三?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)


Translation: 'Overwhelm'

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)


What does 且 mean by itself?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 3)


腦力 the way to say "mental strength" in Cantonese?

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 5)

